# Google maps custom overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, custom-overlay

i was wondering about this project: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

i am wondering how its done, so far i only see pieces of code, it does not say anywhere how this is done, how i can achieve something like this, it does not mention any programs or any IDEs,

all it says, that its using javascript and css, but there is more information on how to do this,

anyone have any idea of how this works ? what i need ? or any tutorials on how to set up a simple overlay ?

Thanks

Comment: ckick that "JAVASCRIPT + HTML" button.  The code you see then, you can copy/paste that code to an empty .html file

Comment: So you mean i can just copy that code, create a hmtl project in intelliJ and paste the code and it would work ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I just double checked.

Comment: Wait @Nesquikk, are you working on Android, or web>

Answer (score 0):

Wait @Nesquikk, are you working on Android or Web? These codes are for web apps, not for Android.

For Android, you would refer to [this page on Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay) for instruction on setting it up in your app.

Comment: Thank you for that, i am working on web app at the moment, but would need it for android as well